# Check the response of a 'Send Event' Logic App action

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a **Logic App** that sends an event to a specified **Event Hub** using the **Send Event** action.

It seems that regardless of whether or not the event is accepted by the specified **Event Hub**, the **Logic App** continues on regardless.  Unlike the **Azure Functions** action, there appears to be no automatically generated `StatusCode` property available for **Send Event** action.

Is it possible to check the response from **Event Hubs** so that I may determain whether or not to halt execution?

---

## Update

After a completed run, it seems that there is a status code returned by Event Hubs, although unusually it seems to be 200 where as typically when sending events it's 201.

[image]

However, when editing the Logig App, there doesn't seem to be any way of accessing that status code in order to check the success/failure of the send event action.

[image]

Comment: There is a status code returned, and action should be marked as failed should it be 4xx/5xx. Can you provide a screenshot of the run history when it was not accepted by Event Hub?

Comment: @DerekLi - I've added an update that hopefully explains my issue a little better.  Basically, I can see the status code in the run results, but I can't seem to access it during the run.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `@outputs('Send_event')?['statusCode']` to access the status code.